# MediaCapture.FramesSources and MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync() Broken

Tags: sdk, camera, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a UWP application which uses the MediaCapture API but since updating to the latest Windows mobile build (slow ring and fast ring), the API is no longer working. This has also been reported by multiple customers.

The CameraFrames UWP sample also crashes showing the error is not in the application code.

Specifically:

MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync() does not return any groups.

Also, _mediaCapture.FramesSources has no items.

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is not reproducible on the latest SDK emulator, but on a later build on multiple physical devices (e.g. Lumia 950XL)

Comment: put a break point on the line you get error (Using F9 key on keyboard) Then see if an exception appears . if it does let me know

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the latest Creators Update builds.

Now raised as an internal bug with Microsoft.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/612